# smarty url paramater that contains special character not getting in $smarty.get.otp

Tags: html, smarty

I am not able to get this otp parameter in smarty because it is ommiting + sign from url.
http://test.com/index.php?otp=+AU7Og==

I have used following code but not getting value  +AU7Og== of otp parameter

```
{$smarty.get.otp|escape:html}
{$smarty.get.otp|escape:htmlall}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a smarty problem. In the query of a URL, + represents a space. You'll have to encode the plus sign if you want to use it as part of a string parameter